# Display price excluding tax ONLY in checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, tax

I'm trying to display prices inclusive of tax in every page, including the cart page. However, I want a full summary of the costs in the checkout page.

I know "Display prices during cart and checkout" can be set to excluding/including. However, I would like to have them Including tax in the cart and excluding tax in the checkout.

How can I archieve this? 
Thanks!